# Хотел чтобы фото были на всю ширину без пробелов. Что за отступы от фотографий?

Tags: html, css

[image: Почему так полилось]

```css
.slider__div {
  height: 660px;
}

.slider__section {
  width: 33%;
  height: 460px;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*justify-content: space-between;*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider__ {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.slider__title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="slider">
          <div class="slider__div">
            <div
              class="slider__section"
              style="background-image: url(Images/1вариант.jpg)"
            >
              <div class="container">
                <div class="slider__">
                  <h2 class="slider__title">ДИЗАЙН И СТРОИТЕЛЬСТВО</h2>
                  <p class="slider__text">
                    Совокупность зданий и сооружений, создающих пространственную
                    среду для жизни и деятельности человека
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              class="slider__section"
              style="background-image: url(Images/2вариант.jpg)"
            >
              <div class="container">
                <div class="slider__">
                  <h2 class="slider__title"></h2>
                  <p class="slider__text"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              class="slider__section"
              style="background-image: url(Images/3вариант.jpg)"
            >
              <div class="container">
                <div class="slider__">
                  <h2 class="slider__title"></h2>
                  <p class="slider__text"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```